# Deliver Emailed or Converted Books to Amazon Cloud Reader and PC Reader

Tags: kindle, amazon, kindle-app, kindle-pc-reader, kindle-cloud-reader

I use the Amazon Cloud Reader and PC Reader, but I can only view books purchased through Amazon in them. In fact, it won't let me deliver other books - those I emailed to Amazon for conversion or created in some other way, like using the Chrome extension - to those readers, at all. See the image for what I run into when I try to deliver one of these books, which was converted using Send-By-Email, from the "Manage My Kindle" area of amazon.com.

[image]

I found a [post on an Amazon forum thread](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx1EFL694HER4E) stating that the Cloud Reader doesn't support personal documents, but it's over a year old. I can't help but think that I'm doing something wrong and missing some way to get these docs into the cloud and/or on my PC.

Is there a way to deliver these docs to Cloud Reader and PC Reader?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I'm familiar with Calibre, but how would it enable me to get these books into the Amazon PC Reader or Cloud Reader? They are already on my other devices.

Comment: Not sure that link is the best way to the solution, so I posted [this](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/920) I have read about, here and there but never tried it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I will keep it in mind if I ever decide to go the personal cloud route. Right now, though, I just want to be able to read my books on all my devices using the existing apps.

Answer (score 1):

### New (April 2014) Solution:

1. Go to Amazon Cloud Drive (https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/).

   Select documents (one-at-a-time only) and click Download.

### Old Solution that can work without Internet Access:

1. Deliver the documents/books to your iPhone or iPad Kindle.

   Download & install an app such as [iFunBox Classic](http://dl.i-funbox.com/) (free). This app allows you to explore your iPhone files with no jailbreak required.

   Plug your iPhone/iPad into PC via USB and start iFunBox Classic.

   In iFunBox, navigate to "User Applications/Kindle/Library".

   Here, every "book" on your Kindle is listed with nonsensical filenames such as "UQCTNAXOJZDZPWDA7GY5GKF52NMNEIU6_PDOC.azw". However, since you just delivered your chosen books, you can sort by date and it will be easy to select the ones you want.

   Drag-and-drop, or select and click "Copy to PC", to get these files onto your PC.

Now you can open them in Kindle for PC, and also Kindle for Mac I believe. Cloud reader is probably a lost cause.

#### Background Info:

As you have discovered, Amazon frustratingly considers any book not purchased through them as a "personal document" with many limitations, including that they do not sync annotations nor highlights, and you cannot deliver them to PC or Cloud Kindle.

#### Extra Tip:

I also use iFunBox to back up my annotations/highlights, contained in the file "AnnotationStorage" located also at "User Applications/Kindle/Library". This is an SQL database and can be read with a free app such as [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Comment: I could not find my PDF documents, which I uploaded from my computer using "send to Kindle", inside my Amazon Drive. I could find and download them from "Manage Your Content and Devices" https://www.amazon.com/mycd