# Can I create my own ebook cloud with Calibre?

Tags: calibre, server

I have heard that I can use [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to create a cloud with all my books, not just ones from a specific vendor.  How would I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and rather easy to do so.

You start it with the `connect/share` button on the main toolbar, then selecting `start content server`; it can be configured from `preferences > sharing`. It should be a simple task, if you need more help just ask. With this method calibre must be running because basically what you are doing is setting up a web interface to connect to it. This way it will be accessible from any web browser. See also [calibre manual](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/gui.html#connect-share) on this topic.

I also suggest you to read [this guide](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Calibre2Opds_Index) from mobileread.

Be sure to protect your content server with a password, so you must be required to login to be able to access it. You don't want to let everyone access your copyrighted ebooks and have to do with piracy.

Comment: I think that start server gives you an OPDS server

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if you have a server available, with PHP, you can install COPS (https://github.com/seblucas/cops/releases) on the server, and use `rsync` to regularly copy your entire Calibre directory to the server. Then you won't need to have Calibre running full time.

Again, it makes sense to protect it with a password.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely create your own eBook library by combining Calibre with other solutions to ensure your books, highlights and comments are reliably accessible online which would require a lot of overhead.

I had a similar problem when we set out to build BookFusion. BookFusion allows you to easily organize, store and read your eBooks and other documents across all devices. You will be able to access them in the cloud while accessing them on any device(Android, IOS and Web). In a gist your own personal ebook cloud library. To learn more visit https://www.bookfusion.com/reading/cloud-library

We also have a Calibre plugin to make creating your cloud library easier. https://www.bookfusion.com/reading/calibre

PS: Founder at BookFusion. Please feel free to respond or DM any feedback or suggestions.

Comment: I have to admit, even though I have a higher rated answer, I am loving BookFusion (which I only heard of through your post). It's particularly helpful since I have yet another bricked Kobo, and relying on reading online or on my phone.

Comment: Thank you for testing and posting back! Please feel free to message me for suggestions or support.